# Compiling / running Java from one folder up

Tags: java

I have the following directory structure:

```
folder1/
    folder2/
        compiler.java
```

For a school assignment, we **have** to be able to run the following commands *from folder1*:

```
javac folder2/compiler.java
java  folder2/compiler
```

The compilation with javac works. When I try to run it with the above java command, I get a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: folder2/compiler (wrong name: compiler)
```

Comment: javac should be emiting the .class files to the same folder (unless yours is configured differently). You should be able to just java compiler in the same directory that the compiler.class file is in.

Comment: Are you sure you are not running `java  folder2.compiler.java` instead of `java folder2.compiler`?

Comment: Banthar: I was running java folder2/compiler.java. When I run java folder2/compiler, I still get an error message (see edited error in question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

If your class `compiler` is in the default package do this. (No package declaration)

```
javac folder2/compiler.java
java -cp folder2/ compiler
```

Otherwise, if your class `compiler` is in the package `folder2` then do this.

```
javac folder2/compiler.java
java -cp . folder2.compiler
```

You can put `complier` in the `folder2` package by putting a package declaration at the top of `compiler.java`

```
package folder2;
```

Comment: Is there no way to be able to run javac folder2/compiler.java then
java folder2/compiler? I have to get those to commands working exactly for a grading script...

Comment: @gonzoc0ding You may omit the `-cp` argument if you set the `CLASSPATH` in the environment. So using my first example, after the `javac` you can do `export CLASSPATH="folder2/"` then `java compiler`. This is assuming a unix-like sh or bash is what you are working from.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
java -cp . folder2.compiler
```

make sure class compiler is in the folder2 package